# SSDT Disable an Restore constraints during Publish

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints, sql-server-data-tools

I'm adding scripts to an SSDT project to manage the addition/update of data from static data tables. Some of these tables reference each other, so I need to be able to shut down the constraints during the update so that I can let the data sit in an inconsistent state until all the scripts are run (I've got a file for table A, and a separate one for Table B).

Once completed, I need to re-enable all the constraints (and let the system check the data to ensure it's consistent). The caveat, is that for various reasons some of the constraints are currently disabled - and I need to ensure that they restore back to the state they were in before my script.

I can't seem to find a view/table that lists the current status of the FK constraints.

Is there any way to have SSDT publish do this automatically? Or if not, can anyone recommend a good solution for doing this?

Comment: You may want to look at sys.foreign_keys to see whether or not the constraint is enabled. You could then set that in a table/variable to know the state of those to set appropriately afterwards. I'd likely still run these in a post-deploy script - probably one script to avoid issues w/ the temp table or table variable.

Comment: Thanks Peter. That worked out - I've managed to record the enabled details and the trusted state (I wanted to restore back to exactly the  same status as before - warts and all). I'll post the script for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I used a combination of sys.Foreign_Keys and sys.check_constraints, since the disable all command disabled both of them. I'm recording the status of the constraints prior to doing my work, then re-enabling them back to the original state at the end.

```
If OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempConstraints') is not null Drop Table #tempConstraints;
GO
IF (SELECT OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpScriptErrors')) IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmpScriptErrors
GO
CREATE TABLE #tmpScriptErrors (Error int)
GO
Create Table #tempConstraints
(
    ConstraintName nVarchar(200),
    TableName nVarchar(200),
    SchemaName nVarchar(200),
    IsNotTrusted bit
);
GO

Begin Tran

Insert into #tempConstraints (ConstraintName, TableName, SchemaName, IsNotTrusted)
Select K.name, object_name(K.parent_object_id), SCHEMA_NAME(T.schema_id), K.Is_Not_Trusted
FROM sys.foreign_keys K 
    Inner Join sys.tables T on K.parent_object_id = T.object_id
Where is_disabled = 0
Union all
Select K.name, object_name(K.parent_object_id), SCHEMA_NAME(T.schema_id), K.Is_Not_Trusted
from sys.check_constraints K
    Inner Join sys.tables T on K.parent_object_id = T.object_id
Where is_disabled = 0


--Disable the Constraints.
Print 'Disabling Constraints'
Exec sp_msforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL';

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--Do Work Here
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Declare @name nvarchar(200);
Declare @table nvarchar(200);
Declare @schema nvarchar(200);
Declare @script nvarchar(max);
Declare @NotTrusted bit;

Declare constraints_cursor CURSOR FOR 
    Select ConstraintName, TableName, SchemaName, IsNotTrusted
    From #tempConstraints;

Open constraints_cursor;

Fetch Next from constraints_cursor
into @name, @table, @schema, @NotTrusted;

While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
Begin
    --Restore each of the Constraints back to exactly the state they were in prior to disabling.

    If @NotTrusted = 1
        Set @script = 'ALTER TABLE [' + @schema + '].[' + @table + '] WITH NOCHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT [' + @name + ']';
    Else
        Set @script = 'ALTER TABLE [' + @schema + '].[' + @table + '] WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT [' + @name + ']';


    exec sp_executesql @script;
    If @@ERROR <> 0
    Begin
        INSERT  INTO #tmpScriptErrors (Error)
        VALUES (1);
    End

    Fetch Next from constraints_cursor
    into @name, @table, @schema, @NotTrusted;
End
Close constraints_cursor;
Deallocate constraints_cursor;

If exists (Select 'x' from #tmpScriptErrors)
    ROLLBACK TRAN;
Else
    COMMIT TRAN;

Drop table #tmpScriptErrors
GO
Drop table #tempConstraints
GO
```